# A question about two random variables over the same sample space

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

The problem is as follows:
Let S be a sample space, and let X and X' be random variables such that X(s) ≥ X'(s) for all s ∈ S. Prove that for any real constant t, 
Pr{X ≥ t}≥Pr{X'≥ t}.

I can understand this intuitively but don't know how to formulate a proof.

Comment: Set up the two integrals and use the inequality to show that one must be greater than the other.

Comment: @JohnDouma "Set up" no integral at all but note this is a statement of the form $P(A)\ge P(A')$ for two events $A$ and $A'$. Now, what can one say about these events?

Comment: @Did Yes, "set up" is a verb phrase. Setup or set-up is a noun.

Comment: @JohnDouma Relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- Prove that $$\{ s|X'(s) \ge t\} \subseteq \{ s|X(s) \ge t\}$$
- That is equivalent to $\forall r \in \{ s|X'(s) \ge t\}$, we have  $r \in \{ s|X(s) \ge t\}$

Comment: That makes sense, but I guess in the second curly brace you mean {s|X(s)>=t}, not {s|X'(s)>=t}. Thx.

Comment: ah yup, thanks, sorry for the typo.